# How can I preserve and refinish 100 year old tile fireplace?

Tags: tile, fireplace

I live in a Craftsman home that is over 100 years old, and we have a gorgeous tile fireplace with a landscape image in the center. Clearly, someone tried to refinish and protect it, but their efforts are flaking off, leaving a surface that is flaking, peeling, and overall cloudy.

I want to remove the old finish and refinish, but am nervous to use the wrong thing and ruin the tiles. It looks like, where the finish is flaking off, there is some white powder collecting on the surface. I suspect is an effect of dampness coming through. Perhaps the re-finish was originally meant to address that, but has outlived its usefulness.

How can I preserve these tiles?

Here are images of what I'm working with:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't think of any "finish" that would tolerate heat as well as the glazing on the tiles does; I'm not surprised the past misguided attempt is flaking off. Not sure how to recover from that mistake other than by re-tiling...

Comment: Tiles are "finished" by covering them with a liquid glaze, then firing them in a kiln at several hundred degrees C for several hours. To refinish them, you'd have to pop them off the wall (likely breaking many) then take them to a local pottery place to see if they can remove the existing glaze and reglaze/fire them for you.

Comment: There are some nice shiny tiles and some very dull looking ones. Which ones do you suspect have the "preservation" effort still in place and which are the failing ones? Have you done anything to try to clean the "white powder" off? Does it just wipe off with a damp rag or does that just make it temporarily shiny and clean looking?

Comment: The shiny bits are the old finish, which is flaking off. The white powdery bits are located on the tile where the finish has already flaked off. That's why I was thinking I could try to remove the old finish and put on a new one. By the way: we live in California on the coast, where it's never cold enough to actually use the fireplace. It's completely decorative. While there is a chimney,  we have never used it as an actual fireplace. So I am not concerned about heat exposure. But I definitely would not attempt to remove the tile! That seems too risky.

Comment: Suggest you reach out to folks like Pasadena Heritage for professional references. That tilework looks too nice to be haphazardly ‘fixed’.